# How to get new transaction coming by address in my waller by json rpc

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

First !! sorry about english language.

I'm newbies dev for ethereum json rpc.
I'm hard to find and i don't understand how to use json rpc for check new transaction coming by my address.??  (i want to get txid if another address send ETH to me)

Please tutorial step by step for check transaction in my wallet address ??

I'm try to use eth_newFilter, eth_getFilterChanges don't working (i'm don't understand)

example if my ethereum address = 0xc6486939a78021ff30b428b52c12fc5315d84136
how to check coming transaction to this address.

Answer (score 1):

1. Iterating through blocks
2. Iterating through transactions of that block
3. verifying if your address makes an appearance

shown below:

```
var blocks = eth.blocknumber;

var txs = [];
for(var i = 0; i < blocks; i++) {
    var block = eth.getBlock(i, true);
    for(var j = 0; j < block.transactions; j++) {
        if( block.transactions[j].to == the_address )
            txs.push(block.transactions[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this does not detect ETH balance if the transaction came through a smart contract. Smart contract based wallets include e.g. Gnosis SAFE. Currently there is no API on RPC level to detect  this. In a smart contract wallet, the "to" field is the smart contract address and then the actual transfer of ETH value are done using EVM instructions.